# Must declare the scalar variable @firstname

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am using parameterised query but I got an error - how can I solve it?

Here is my code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
string sql = @"insert into Student_Records (FirstName,LastName,Email,ContactNumber,DOB,TemporaryAddress,PermanentAddress,FatherName,Fathersoccupation,ContactNumberF,MotherName,Mothersoccupation,ContactNumberM,Remarks) values(@firstname,@lastname,@email,@contactnumber,@dob,@temporaryaddress,@permanentaddress,@fathername,@fatheroccupation,@contactnumberf,@mothername,@motheroccupation,@contactnumberm,@remarks) ";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txtFname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtlastN.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactnumber", txtCN.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dtdob.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@temporaryaddress", txtTaddress.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@permanentaddress", txtPaddress.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fathername", txtFname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fatheroccupation", txtFoccupation.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactnumberf", txtFcn.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mothername", txtMname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@motheroccoupation", txtMoccupation.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactnumberm", txtMcn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", rtremarks.Text);
DBconnection.ExecutiveNonQuery(sql);
```

I get this error:

> must declare the scalar variable

Comment: You're not using `SqlCommand`. Sure, you're creating it and populating parameters, but you're not using it to run your command.

Comment: This can't the code you're actually using, as `ExecutiveNonQuery` wouldn't compile? I suspect the problem is that you're not adding a parameter for **@email** not @firstname. If you could copy and paste the problematic code and error **verbatim** we might be able to help better.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Add your insert cmd", connection)) {
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txtFname.Text);
   ....
}
```